# How to check table using textbox value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I need to select checkbox on the basis on textbox value, for ex: if I enter 5 in textbox then I click select all checkbox after that only first 5 rows of table should be select,else it should select all checkbox. how i can is achieve this using angularjs, I have attached below code please go through that

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.Customers = [{
      CustomerId: 1,
      Name: "John Hammond",
      Country: "United States",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2,
      Name: "Mudassar Khan",
      Country: "India",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3,
      Name: "Suzanne Mathews",
      Country: "France",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 4,
      Name: "Robert Schidner",
      Country: "Russia",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2,
      Name: "Mudassar Khan",
      Country: "India",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3,
      Name: "Suzanne Mathews",
      Country: "France",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2,
      Name: "Mudassar Khan",
      Country: "India",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3,
      Name: "Suzanne Mathews",
      Country: "France",
      Selected: false
    }
  ];

  $scope.CheckUncheckHeader = function() {
    $scope.IsAllChecked = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Customers.length; i++) {
      if (!$scope.Customers[i].Selected) {
        $scope.IsAllChecked = false;
        break;
      }
    };
  };
  $scope.CheckUncheckHeader();

  $scope.CheckUncheckAll = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Customers.length; i++) {
      $scope.Customers[i].Selected = $scope.IsAllChecked;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th align="left">
        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="IsAllChecked" ng-change="CheckUncheckAll()" />
                        CustomerId</label>
        <br>
        <input id="txtCheckCount" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="chkCount" style="width: 45px;"></input>
      </th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Country
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="chkCustomer_{{m.CustomerId}}">
                            <input id="chkCustomer_{{m.CustomerId}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="m.Selected" ng-change="CheckUncheckHeader()" />
                            {{m.CustomerId}}
                        </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{m.Name}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{m.Country}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `I have attached below code please go through that` - IMHO kinda strange statement...

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there :). I just took the value from the input's ngModel. Parsed it, if it is a number and it is less then the total count it will use it in the loop, otherwise it uses the length (what it was in your original post). See the code below.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.Customers = [{
      CustomerId: 1,
      Name: "John Hammond",
      Country: "United States",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2,
      Name: "Mudassar Khan",
      Country: "India",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3,
      Name: "Suzanne Mathews",
      Country: "France",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 4,
      Name: "Robert Schidner",
      Country: "Russia",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2,
      Name: "Mudassar Khan",
      Country: "India",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3,
      Name: "Suzanne Mathews",
      Country: "France",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2,
      Name: "Mudassar Khan",
      Country: "India",
      Selected: false
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3,
      Name: "Suzanne Mathews",
      Country: "France",
      Selected: false
    }
  ];

  $scope.CheckUncheckHeader = function() {
    $scope.IsAllChecked = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Customers.length; i++) {
      if (!$scope.Customers[i].Selected) {
        $scope.IsAllChecked = false;
        break;
      }
    };
  };
  $scope.CheckUncheckHeader();

  $scope.CheckUncheckAll = function() {
var chkCnt = parseInt($scope.chkCount);
if(chkCnt > $scope.Customers.length || isNaN(chkCnt)){
chkCnt = $scope.Customers.length
}
    for (var i = 0; i < chkCnt; i++) {
      $scope.Customers[i].Selected = $scope.IsAllChecked;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th align="left">
        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="IsAllChecked" ng-change="CheckUncheckAll()" />
                        CustomerId</label>
        <br>
        <input id="txtCheckCount" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="chkCount" style="width: 45px;"></input>
      </th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Country
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="chkCustomer_{{m.CustomerId}}">
                            <input id="chkCustomer_{{m.CustomerId}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="m.Selected" ng-change="CheckUncheckHeader()" />
                            {{m.CustomerId}}
                        </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{m.Name}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{m.Country}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks i did the same thing but in my project getting error bcz of other condition.